# Scaling API design

Tags: java, solr

I'll try to explain the problem in the best way.

Assume, my application name is app1. It's heavy application. Here heavy means more code.

What my application does?
        It's kind of **rest web application**. **Data source** for the application is **SOLR**. **We have around 17 million records in SOLR.**

We pass date-range and get the data from solr, do basic calculations and return the response. 
We pass key and get the data.
We calculates pivot in solr.

All the use cases are very fast. We have around **10 solr nodes**. SOLR gives **response less than 5 seconds** for all most all the cases.

Here the problem comes:

For a mobile application, we are **testing for 5000 hits**. I mean 5000 REST calls at the same time.

App is running on **weblogic server**. We have **8 instances of app running**. And these instances reading data from 10 solr nodes.

5000 hits doesn't meet SLA. It started failing for few rest api's after 300hits.

Here the question comes:

**How do I scale it?** So that all hits succeeds.

Adding rest app instances or solr nodes or enhancing codes or

splitting rest apis into parts [heavy, light].Heavy apis will be given more solr, rest instnaces.

Or

is there any other way?

I feel code is written in the best way. But I agree there will always be improvement. I am saying this because app gives response very quickly. But in my use case, how do i scale?

Comment: do you have a diagram to explain from the time a request enters your system and response is sent to client?

Comment: if you just have one instance running on weblogic and 10 SOLR nodes, than by first thought I'd say your single instance is your bottleneck. Especially because your calls can result in an average of 5 seconds work, which have good potential of saturating your resources during spikes (such as your test). Are you using a cloud provider to host your app?

Comment: @Edd I mentioned 8 instances of web logic server.

Comment: oh my! sorry about that

Comment: Just to understand, given that 5 seconds is the longer request what's the average? 100ms, 500ms, 1sec? You should also give us more information about the stress test, how much are different the requests you're using during the stress test. All different? When possible I takes a day/week production log and use it to simulate the test in a shorter period of time.

Comment: @freedev I would say heavy api takes average 5 seconds. Light api takes average 3 seconds. All same apis. 2000hits to the same api at the same time.

Comment: @GopsAB Given your specs how long a request can be cached (i.e. for all the client you'll return the same answer for 1 second, 5 second, 1 minute).

Comment: @freedev If i understood your question correctly, we are not caching the response. For every request, we are reading from SOLR, does the calculation, displays the response.

Comment: @GopsAB Well... given that you're not caching, if you can, how long can you cache **your response** in order to respect application specs (1 second, 5 second, 1 minute, more...)

Comment: @freedev Data is more dynamic. We need live data. We are actually migrating to event based concept. So data will be changing in SOLR in near real time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139467/discussion-between-freedev-and-gops-ab).